# Loop nesting issue - values not correct

Tags: python, loops, pandas, numpy, if-statement

I have a dataframe that has two relevant columns (actually has >2, but don't think that's important), and one of the columns has duplicates in it.

The duplicates are in the column, HAB_slice['Radial Position'], and are in increments of 0.1.

Ideally, I want to say if two values in HAB_slice['Radial Position'] are equal to each other, find the absolute value difference between them and add them to a running total.

The current code looks like this:

```
    possible_pos = np.linspace(0, 1, 1 / stepsize+1) 
    center_sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(possible_pos)): 
        temp = HAB_slice[HAB_slice['Radial Position']==possible_pos[i]]
        if len(temp) == 2:
            center_sum += np.abs(temp['I'].diff().values[1])
    print center_sum
```

And while it does return a value and doesn't throw errors, the value for center_sum is different than when I manually calculate it. I think it's just something wrong with the nesting but I'm pretty new to loops and am not really sure.

Example of the error: the following data yields a center_sum = 0 in this code, but if you manually calculate the absolute value differences in I when the Radial positions are equal to each other, it equals 0.0045878.

```
I           Radial Position
0.14289522  1
0.14298554  0.9
0.1430356   0.8
0.1430454   0.7
0.1430552   0.6
0.14266456  0.5
0.14227392  0.4
0.14234106  0.3
0.14286598  0.2
0.1433909   0.1
0.14309062  0
0.14279034  0.1
0.14271344  0.2
0.14285992  0.3
0.1430064   0.4
0.14327248  0.5
0.14353856  0.6
0.14356664  0.7
0.14335672  0.8
0.1431468   0.9
0.14338368  1
```

Edit: I've simplified things with sample code to try and get it working.

```
test1 = [[0.14309062,0],[0.1433909,0.1], [0.14286598,0.2], [0.14234106,0.3], 
[0.14279034,0.1], [0.14271344,0.2], [0.14285992,0.3]]
'''
test2 = [[0.14289522,1],[0.14298554,0.9],[0.1430356,0.8],[0.1430454,0.7],
[0.1430552,0.6],[0.14266456,0.5],[0.14227392,0.4],[0.14234106,0.3],
[0.14286598,0.2],[0.1433909,0.1],[0.14309062,0],[0.14279034,0.1],
[0.14271344,0.2],[0.14285992,0.3],[0.1430064,0.4],[0.14327248,0.5],
[0.14353856,0.6],[0.14356664,0.7],[0.14335672,0.8],[0.1431468,0.9],
[0.14338368,1]]
'''
stepsize = 0.1
possible_pos = np.linspace(0, 1, 1 / stepsize+1) 
HAB_slice = pd.DataFrame(test1)
HAB_slice.columns = ['I', 'Radial Position']
```

Comment: Smells like floating pt issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It should work.

```
possible_pos = np.linspace(0, 1, 1 / stepsize+1) 
center_sum = 0

for i in range(0, len(possible_pos)):

    # retriving index position of the step value 
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(HAB_slice['Radial Position']) if x == possible_pos[i]]

    # if multiple value exist for the postion
    if len(indices) > 1:
        values = [x for i, x in enumerate(HAB_slice['I']) if i in indices]
        center_sum += np.abs(np.diff(values))

    # if single value exist for the position
    elif len(indices) == 1:
        center_sum += HAB_slice['I'][indices[0]]

    # if no value exist for the position
    else: continue  

print center_sum
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I use that code, I get an index error: index 11 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 11 from the line that defines indices. Since I don't know what i for i is doing, I'm not even sure where to start with finding the issue it's complaining about.

Comment: With the shortened test case of [[0.14309062,0],[0.1433909,0.1], [0.14286598,0.2], [0.14234106,0.3], [0.14279034,0.1], [0.14271344,0.2], [0.14285992,0.3]], it doesn't error but it also supplies two values for center_sum instead of one and neither of them correspond to the hand calculated value of 0.00127196

Comment: the i in " i for i, x " is the index position(counter) for the current step value. The enumerate() function adds a counter to an list as (counter, element).

Comment: How are you representing the data? In your question you have posted it as two different list but in the comment you are representing it as a single list with the data couple together. The iteration over the data will change based on your data representation.

Comment: I added an update above to show you what I've been trying to test with. test1 is a tiny subset, which doesn't throw an error but also the value isn't correct (center_sum for test1 should equal 0.00127196) and actually there are two values.